# Get a list of Exams for a Student on an SQL Database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create an asp.net core web api.
So i wrote these classes for a Student with a list of Exams:

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; init; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public List<Exam>? Exams { get; init; }
}

public class Exam
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; init; }

    public string? Type { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
}
```

On my database i have both classes as tables, though the exams table has an extra column holding the Id of the student the exam belongs to.
My database context class looks like this

```
public class LehrerDBContext : DbContext
{
    public LehrerDBContext(DbContextOptions<LehrerDBContext> options) : base(options) {

    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Exam> Exams { get; set; }
}
```

if i do `_dbContext.Students.ToList()` now, it returns me a List with all students but the students' exam lists are null.
The database tables look like this:
[image: students table]
[image: exams table]

Feel free to ask if something is unclear as this is my first stack overflow question.

I tried adding a getter function to the student's exam list, that gets all exams by the students Id, though i don't know how to get a database context here.

Comment: Lazy loading may be turned off. Include the object: _dbContext.Students.Include(i => i.Exams).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/read-related-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to learn how to load related data(Eager loading,Explicit loading,Lazy loading)

If you want to try with Lazy loading,you have to  install this package:

[image]

regist your dbcontext as below:

```
services.AddDbContext<yourdbcontext>(options => 
            {
                options.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("yourdbcontext"));
            }) ;
```

Set the navigation properties as virtual

```
public virtual List<Exam> Exams { get; set; }
```

Result:

[image]